# Pointers in C : Difference in the two declarations

Tags: c, pointers

What do the following declarations in C mean  :

```
char far *far *scr;
char far far** scr;
```

From what I gather the first statement is a pointer of type pointer to far? 
And the second is a pointer to a pointer of type far ?

Comment: @haccks I don't know! I was given this declaration and I was supposed to tell what they meant!

Comment: Typically, 'far' is a remnant of the past. On 16-bit 8086/286-based architectures, there were two classes of pointers, near (16-bit offset only) and far (16-bit segment base + 16-bit offset). Nowadays 'far', if at all present, is usually a macro resolving to nothing.

Comment: read about pointers here [link](http://armantutorial.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/incrementing-pointers-to-pointers-in-c-programming/)[/link]

Comment: @rm_beginners page not found

Comment: I'm just surprised they used scr instead of away

Comment: http://armantutorial.wordpress.com/2014/07/15/incrementing-pointers-to-pointers-in-c-programming/

Comment: Strictly speaking: far is not a reserved word in C, so the lines above are not valid C. far may be a #define that we do not see here or it may be a compiler extension for far pointers (as other comments already stated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`far` is not a standard keyword in C, so its exact meaning and semantics depend on the compiler. In general, it applies to segmented memory architectures where a “far” pointer can point outside the current segment, and a “near” pointer only within the segment. Nowadays you are probably doing embedded development if you need to worry about such things.

As for your syntax examples, the placement of the `far` qualifier differs by compiler. Some compilers use it similarly to `const` (i.e., it goes on the right side of the `*` when it refers to that pointer), but many popular compilers place it on the left side instead, as though it referred to the data and not the pointer. This appears to be the case in your example, which would make the first (`char far *far *`) a far pointer to a far pointer. But second (`char far far**`) would then be a non-qualified (near, if that is the default) pointer to a “far far” pointer. Personally I'm not aware of a compiler that has such a concept, and would guess that the other `far` is either redundant or an error, but, like said, this is non-standard. Maybe some compiler implements a “huge” pointer as `far far`…