# Complicated pointer declaration

Tags: c, pointers

Recently, I encountered a question asking the difference between these two declarations.

```
char far *far *scr;
char far far **scr;
```

Now, I know that in the first declaration,

```
char far *far *scr;
```

src is a far pointer, which contains the address of a far pointer to a char
i.e src is a far pointer to a far pointer to a char.

However, I don't seem to understand what the second declaration means.
Does it mean that src is a pointer, which contains the address of a far pointer to a char?
If so, then is the second declaration the same as
`char far ** src` ??

Comment: `far` is not part of the C language. It probably is an extension of your specific compiler.

Comment: I think your doubt after seeing [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754002/pointers-in-c-difference-in-the-two-declarations). And some explanation is [here](http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/complicated-declarations/discussion-628).

Comment: Only 3 hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24754002/pointers-in-c-difference-in-the-two-declarations

Comment: far is a a non-standard far qualifier (from dos-era for for segmented memory model) and should not be a part of portable C code. As the name `scr` (short for screen) implies, it is possibly used to write directly into memory buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably read those declarations as

```
char far *far *scr;
// scr is a far pointer to a far pointer to char
// char (far *)(far *)scr;

char far far **scr;
// scr is a pointer to a far far pointer to char
// char (far far *)*scr;
```

Comment: I have absolutely no idea (*I know what a `long long` pointer is*). I don't know the extension your compiler uses. Nevertheless, without more information, that is how I would read the declaration.